# how to set MAAS for "power type" on VM created with VMware Fusion

Tags: maas, vmware-fusion

home lab:

- 1 VM with Ubuntu 16.04Lts for MAAS Region Controller
- 2 VM with Ubuntu 16.04Lts for MAAS Rack Controller (DNS & DHCP), each one with 2 virtual network adapter
- 1 vNode with Ubuntu 16.04Lts for each Rack Controller

on VMware Fusion

[image]

on MAAS Region Controller

[image]

the vnodes are added

[image]

but I don't know how to set the power type to be able to start the commissiong of vnodes via MAAS. Anyone can help me please? I think that solution is wrong

[image]

someone knows how to resolve that?

Answer (score -1):

If you using MAAS version 2.1, The power type for VMs are created in VMware is **VMware**.

[image: MAAS]

You can choose `Virsh` which your VMs are created in `KVM Hypervisor`.

You can look at [this documentation](https://docs.maas.io/2.1/en/installconfig-nodes-power-types).

Hopely can help you.

Comment: the version is the 2.1.2+bzr5555-0ubuntu1 (16.04.1), the last one. Do you know the right sentence to use to fill the form to run the BMC for vmware fusion? thanks